# Multiple JLeft Outer Join in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I have the following classes:

```
public class ItemGroupParameterBase : Master
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
}

public class ItemBase : Master
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
}

public class ItemParameter : Master
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int GroupDetailID { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The Master class have the common ID. I need to display all the Group Parameter Names from ItemGroupParameterBase and Value from the Item Parameter. The result is based on my item selection from the combobox. Even if the value is not found i need to show the Group Parameter Name. I tried like below.

```
var source = from itemGroupParameters in _job.ItemGroupParameterList
             join items in _job.ItemList.Where(x => x.ID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbItem.SelectedValue)) on itemGroupParameters.GroupID equals items.GroupID  into g1
             from featureNames in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join itemParameters in _job.ItemParameterList.Where(x => x.ItemID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbItem.SelectedValue)) on featureNames.ID equals itemParameters.GroupDetailID into g2
             from itemSubParameters in g2
             select new
             {
                 FeatureName = featureNames.Name,
                 Value = (itemSubParameters != null ? itemSubParameters.Value : String.Empty) 
             };
```

It shows null reference.

Comment: No I checked the index and then only populate data. IF i remove the last join part it is working the left outer part is the problem. if the third line deleted from the query, it is working but that gives only the data if data is also available in the itemparameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Actually i missed `DefaultIfEmpty()`. Now its working and the query is below

```
var source = from itemGroupParameters in _job.ItemGroupParameterList
             join items in _job.ItemList.Where(x => x.ID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbItem.SelectedValue)) on itemGroupParameters.GroupID equals items.GroupID
             join itemParameters in _job.ItemParameterList.Where(x => x.ItemID == Convert.ToInt32(cmbItem.SelectedValue)) on itemGroupParameters.ID equals itemParameters.GroupDetailID into g1
             from itemSubParameters in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new
             {
                 FeatureName = itemGroupParameters.Name,
                 Value = (itemSubParameters != null ? itemSubParameters.Value : String.Empty)
             };
```